# Unit length tangent vectors on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, riemannian-geometry, fiber-bundles

Let $X$ be a Riemannian manifold and $TX$ its tangent bundle. Is there a name for the $S^1$-bundle given by the unit length tangent vectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is only an $S^1$-bundle when $X$ is a surface. In general it's called the sphere bundle of $X$ or unit tangent bundle and is an $S^{n-1}$-bundle when $\dim X = n$. :)

Comment: Yes, that's it. I knew it had a name. Thanks.